# The following code is not running

Tags: jquery, html, coldfusion, dreamweaver, coldfusion-8

Please consider the following lines of code which I'm trying to integrate:

Part I:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Part II:

```
<script> var processFinish = false; 
         var tf_dialog_count; 
         var tf_dialog_counter;
         function verifyMe(u,key,fname,status) 
         { 

         if(processFinish) 
         { 
             tf_dialog_count = 0; 
             return true; } 
         else { 
             if(typeof status === 'undefined') 
             { $("body").append("<div id='tf_dialog'><p></p></div>");
             var unameVal = $("#"+u).val(); 
             var surl = 'http://someurl.com/username/filename.cfc?method=generateToken&uname='+unameVal+'&key='+key+'&callback=?'; 
             var retRes = false; 
             $.getJSON(surl, function(data) 
             { 
                 if(parseInt(data.RESULT) == 1) 
                   { $("#tf_dialog").html(data.MSG); 
                   $("#tf_dialog").append("<br>Time Remaining <span id='tf_dialog_counter'></span> secs"); 
                   $("#tf_dialog").append("<br><span id='tf_dialog_waiting'>Waiting</span>"); 
                   $("#tf_dialog").dialog({ height: 200 }); 
                   tf_dialog_count = 20; 
                   tf_dialog_counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); 
                   setInterval(function() { verifyMe(unameVal,key,fname,'checkStatus'); },7000); 
                   return false; } 
                   else { 
                   alert(data.MSG); 
                   return false; 
                        } }) } 
                   else { if (tf_dialog_count > 0) 
                   { var surl = 'http://someurl.com/username/filename.cfc?method=getStatus&uname='+u+'&key='+key+'&callback=?';
                    $.getJSON(surl, function(data) { $("#tf_dialog_waiting").animate({fontSize:"22px"},3500,function(){ $(this).animate({fontSize:"10px"},3500); });
                     if(parseInt(data.RESULT) == 1)
                      { processFinish = true; $('#'+fname).submit(); } 
                      else { return false; } }); 
                      } } return false; } } 
                      function timer() 
                      { tf_dialog_count=tf_dialog_count-1; 
                      if (tf_dialog_count <= 0) 
                      { clearInterval(tf_dialog_counter); processFinish = false; 
                      $("#tf_dialog").html(""); 
                      $("#tf_dialog").dialog("destroy"); 
                      $("#tf_dialog").remove(); 
                      alert("Time out. Please try again!!"); 
                      } $('#tf_dialog_counter').html(tf_dialog_count); 
                      } </script>
```

Part III:

I need to put the following code for `onSubmit` attribute:

```
return verifyMe('<username_textbox_id>','<key>','<form_id>')
```

I have created a log in form (ColdFusion) and trying to run the code but wondering what is wrong in my code. Please let me know if I'm putting wrong variables.

Here is the whole code I have  used so far in Dreamweaver:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Login Form</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script> var processFinish = false; 
         var tf_dialog_count; 
         var tf_dialog_counter;

         function verifyMe(u,key,fname,status) 
         { 
         if(processFinish) 
         { 
             tf_dialog_count = 0; 
             return true; } 
         else { 
             if(typeof status === 'undefined') 
             { $("body").append("<div id='tf_dialog'><p></p></div>");
             var unameVal = $("#"+u).val(); 
             var surl = 'http://someurl.com/username/filename.cfc?method=generateToken&uname='+unameVal+'&key='+key+'&callback=?'; 
             var retRes = false; 
             $.getJSON(surl, function(data) 
             { 
                 if(parseInt(data.RESULT) == 1) 
                   { $("#tf_dialog").html(data.MSG); 
                   $("#tf_dialog").append("<br>Time Remaining <span id='tf_dialog_counter'></span> secs"); 
                   $("#tf_dialog").append("<br><span id='tf_dialog_waiting'>Waiting</span>"); 
                   $("#tf_dialog").dialog({ height: 200 }); 
                   tf_dialog_count = 20; 
                   tf_dialog_counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); 
                   setInterval(function() { verifyMe(unameVal,key,fname,'checkStatus'); },7000); 
                   return false; } 
                   else { 
                   alert(data.MSG); 
                   return false; 
                        } }) } 
                   else { if (tf_dialog_count > 0) 
                   { var surl = 'http://someurl.com/username/filename.cfc?method=getStatus&uname='+u+'&key='+key+'&callback=?';
                    $.getJSON(surl, function(data) { $("#tf_dialog_waiting").animate({fontSize:"22px"},3500,function(){ $(this).animate({fontSize:"10px"},3500); });
                     if(parseInt(data.RESULT) == 1)
                      { processFinish = true; $('#'+fname).submit(); } 
                      else { return false; } }); 
                      } } return false; } } 
                      function timer() 
                      { tf_dialog_count=tf_dialog_count-1; 
                      if (tf_dialog_count <= 0) 
                      { clearInterval(tf_dialog_counter); processFinish = false; 
                      $("#tf_dialog").html(""); 
                      $("#tf_dialog").dialog("destroy"); 
                      $("#tf_dialog").remove(); 
                      alert("Time out. Please try again!!"); 
                      } $('#tf_dialog_counter').html(tf_dialog_count); 
                      } </script>
</head>
<body>
<p> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
<div align = "center">
<cfform id = "form_id" action="" method="POST"  onSubmit = "return verifyMe('<username_textbox_id>','<key>','<form_id>')">
Username:<br> 
<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<cfinput type="text" name="uname" id = "uname" />
<br>
<p> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
Password:<br/> 
<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<cfinput type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd" /><br>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<cfinput type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"  />
</cfform>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you check the error console of your browser?

Comment: Nothing happens after clicking submit button on my browser. I just checked the error console of my browser and I see lot of errors of the following types:

`Timestamp: 6/26/2013 8:16:01 AM
Warning: Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped.
Source File: http://l-stat.livejournal.com/??.8e797?v=1372155425
Line: 368, Column: 19
Source Code:
 background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#FFF2F0), to(#FED4D3));`

Comment: I hope you don't use angle brackets in the actual code invocation and just used them here as placeholders, right? I mean in this construction: `verifyMe('<username_textbox_id>','<key>','<form_id>')` :-)

Comment: @JuraKhrapunov I did use angle brackets there in actual code. What should I replace it with?

Comment: Oh dude, since you are using these parameters as jQuery selectors ( in $("#"+u) construction) they should be passed exactly as mentioned in the code, try to use `return verifyMe('uname','key','form_id')`. ANd not sure where `key` param comes from...

Comment: @JuraKhrapunov Thanks. I'm new to jQuery. I think it worked but I'm gettting a message after putting username and password. The message is:

`Invalid Key Used for authentication`. Does this have to do anything with the code?

Comment: Also, what about the `action` attribute, isn't it involved for the proper functionality of the code? I left it blank.

Comment: As I said, you are passing "key" parameter to the function as `key` argument inside the function and using it in the URL contruction. It effectively uses string "key" as key, hence it is invalid. You might want to pass to the verify function actual key as a second argument

Comment: @JuraKhrapunov Thanks for your reply. I'm little confused. Could you please tell me what precisely I need to pass for `Username` and `Password`. Thanks

Comment: I have no idea :-), it all depends on how do you want to process submitted data. Currently form submits to itself (empty "action" attribute of the <form> tag), which means that you have to detect form submissions on top of the page, process data and do something useful :-)